# Filter Column by Color - Excel Javascript

Tags: excel, filter, office-js, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm trying to filter a column for text that is Red Font but I can't quite get it.

Ive read these docs which show its possible, but I can't get it to work--> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.filtercriteria?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-filtercriteria-color-member

Here is what I have so far and I just get "invalid" when trying to run:

```
var range = ws.getUsedRange(true)
var condition = {
    filterOn: Excel.FilterOn.FontColor,
    FontColor: "red"
}
ws.autoFilter.apply(range, Desc_Col_Index, condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/jakobpn/16193d2cfdb5b2526fb9a9d4f46d9f70) in Script Lab. It will filter the used range of the sheet to only show rows where the cell color of the second column is red. It is easy to change it to filter on the font (text) color.

I made a few changes to your code:

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
  const range = sheet.getUsedRange(true);
  const condition: Excel.FilterCriteria = {
    filterOn: Excel.FilterOn.cellColor, // Change this to .fontColor to filter on text color
    color: "red"
  }
  sheet.autoFilter.apply(range, 1, condition);
  await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: I'm curious why would you use another programming language then the one asked in OP? I'm clearly not using Typescript. Additionally, you've have answered the question with filtering by Cell Color not Font?

Comment: Your answer did help, for one, I noticed that I was using `FontColor` with a capital `F`. Quite annoying when you can find both on the docs --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.filteron?view=excel-js-preview

Comment: Glad it helped you despite the use of TypeScript. The salient change is the same for JavaScript and TypeScript.